# Character indicies 8,10 do not correspond to the start and end of a token

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

- **Built with:** Bot Framework Composer (v1.1.1)
- **Deploying with:** `provisionComposer.js`
- **Publishing with:** Bot Framework Composer (v1.1.1) (Error occurs here)

I am following the steps on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot#deploy-to-new-azure-resources. I created the JSON with new resources and resource group using the provisionComposer.js method described on this page. The gif shows the steps I took. Once `provisionComposer.js` returned the JSON and the resources were created, I went over to Bot Framework Composer and created a new profile and pasted the JSON into that profile. I clicked publish button in Bot Framework Composer and got the following error:

```
{
    "text": "Character indicies 8,10 do not correspond to the start and end of a token.",
    "errCode": 24
}
```

Comment: can you double-check all the steps and settings just to be sure that you didn't miss out on anything?